# Populating struct resembling an IP Header with nibbles/sub-8-bit values

Tags: c++, networking, bit-manipulation

I've been wanting to get into networking with raw sockets recently and have decided to perform a generic ICMP ping using C++ and raw sockets.

I started with making a struct called `IP_Header`, defined as such:

```
struct IP_Header {
    uint8_t version : 4;
    uint8_t IHL : 4;

    uint8_t DSCP : 6;
    uint8_t ECN : 2;

    uint16_t total_len;
    uint16_t ident;
    

    uint16_t flags : 3;
    uint16_t frag_offset : 13;

    uint8_t ttl;
    uint8_t proto;
    uint16_t header_chksum;
    uint32_t src;
    uint32_t dst;

    
};
```

And so i populated this struct with some default values:

```
void populateHeaderDefault(IP_Header* ip) {

    ip->version = 4;
    ip->IHL = 5;

    ip->DSCP = 0;
    ip->ECN = 0;

    ip->total_len = htons(20); //header only
    ip->ident = htons(1);


    ip->flags = 2;
    ip->frag_offset = 0;


    ip->ttl = 64;
    ip->proto = IPPROTO::IPPROTO_HOPOPTS;
    ip->header_chksum = 0;


    IN_ADDR ia;

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.178.31", &ia);
    ip->src = ia.S_un.S_addr;

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &ia);
    ip->dst = ia.S_un.S_addr;


    ip->header_chksum = header_checksum(ip, sizeof IP_Header);

}
```

However, the resulting IP Header Version/IHL contains 0x54 instead of 0x45, and the short that contains the Flags and Fragmentation is 0x0200 instead 0f 0x4000. (I'm comparing my values to an exact copy of the packet recreated in scapy)

So my question is how I would fix these values? I know manually assigning the right value would probably work, but I'd like to use nibbles for better accessability.

Comment: Bitfields can be laid out in arbitrary order. The answer is don't use bitfields.

Comment: Not to mention that the compiler is allowed to add padding in the structure as well.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is how I would fix these values?

The values in the struct are already correct. The problem is in how you use the value. You simply cannot rely on order of bit fields.

Here is a correct way to get 0x45 from the Version/IHL:

```
uint8_t verIHL = ip->version << 4 | ip->IHL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare version and header length bitfields based on host machine byte order similar to [Linux IP header](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux/include/uapi/linux/ip.h#L86) as shown below, which will make sure right values set.

```
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
        __u8    ihl:4,
                version:4;
#elif defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
        __u8    version:4,
                ihl:4;
#else
#error  "Please fix <asm/byteorder.h>"
#endif
```

Secondly, you can define IP flags supported and set required values as below,

```
#define IP_FLAG_RF 0x8000                 /* reserved fragment flag */
#define IP_FLAG_DF 0x4000                 /* dont fragment flag */
#define IP_FLAG_MF 0x2000                 /* more fragments flag */

ip->flags = htons(IP_FLAG_DF);
```